# Define a callback for a function that utlizies DATA parameter from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, callback

I am trying to save the HTML from a `<textarea>` as an email template.  This can be done in multiple places so I want to create a `save_email_template()` function that can receive parameters and save as needed (which I've sucessfulyl done).

I also want to specifiy a callback each time the  `save_email_template()` function is called. The catch is inside the callback I want to handle the `data` returned from an ajax call inside the `save_email_template()` function in a variety of ways.

Here is my code:

```
function save_email_template(options,callback){

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/save_email_template.php',
      data: options.params,
      success:function(data) {

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(data);
        }
      }
   });
 }


   save_email_template({
      params: {
        'action':'add',
        'eid':$('input#id').val(),
        'title':$('input#name').val(),
        'html':$('textarea#html').val()
      }
    }, function(data){ // <----  "Data" Not Defined 

        if (typeof data.html_issues !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('HTML Issues:\n------------------');
            console.error(data.html_issues);
        }

        if (typeof data.css_issues !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('CSS Issues:\n------------------');
            console.error(data.css_issues);
        }

        if (data.status == "OK") {
             $('body').append(data.html);
        } else {
            if (typeof data.error_msg !== 'undefined')
              alert(data.error_msg);

            if (data.status == "ERROR")
              console.error(data);
        }
    });
```

**THE ISSUE:**

I keep getting the JS error '"data" not defined'  and its referencing my callback... this code `function(data){...}`. Obviosly `data` is not yet defined, but how to I reference the `data` returned in the AJAX call?

Comment: Don't pass the callback into your `save_email_template()` function. Instead, return the ajax call from the function and write a `.done()` or `.then()` handler on the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) that is returned.

Comment: @dave TBH, there is nothing wrong with a callback... DigitalMC: I do not clearly understand the question and I don't see why you get that error. Is that the full code?

Comment: @dave wouldn't I have to put the `save_email_template()` function in a variable to access the return? I'm a little confused on how to set that up.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon Yes full code. Basically my browser is saying "data" doesn't exist yet when I define it in the callback as a parameter. I'll update the code to clarify.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon depends by what you mean "nothing wrong." Can it work, yes, but he said he wants to handle things differently in a variety of ways, presumably different when called from different places.

Comment: @DigitalMC change your function to return the ajax call. Literally `return $.ajax(...)`. Then to handle the response `save_email_template(options).then(function(data) { ... });`

Comment: @Dave that totally worked! Thanks so much for you help and quick response. I didn't know you could do that with an AJAX call.

Comment: I don't see a reason that your original code wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. I added this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the callback into your `save_email_template()` function. Instead, return the ajax call from the function and write a `.done()` or `.then()` handler on the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) that is returned. This allows you to call the function and define the callback logic in the same area of the code.

```
function save_email_template(options){
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/save_email_template.php',
      data: options.params
    });
}

save_email_template(options).then(function(data) {
    //write your callback logic here
});
```